# basics of using cut awk grep and sed

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to extract the year from this output :

```
sam@sam-laptop:~/shell$ date
Mon Feb  8 21:57:00 CET 2010

sam@sam-laptop:~/shell$ date | cut -d' ' -f7
2010

sam@sam-laptop:~/shell$ date | awk '{print $6}'
2010
```

Are there any other ways to get the same result ? using maybe grep, sed etc ?
Merci !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some `sed` variations:

```
date | sed 's/.* //'

date | sed 's/.*\(....\)$/\1/'

date | sed 's/.*\(.\{4\}\)$/\1/'

date | sed -r 's/.*(.{4})$/\1/'

date | sed -r 's/.*([[:digit:]]{4})$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're really just looking for the current year from `date`, you might consider just running this directly.

```
date +%Y
```

No post-processing needed. :)

---

***Update:* Comments on text processing** (since the OP is looking for those)

`cut`/`awk`/`sed` are great for pulling apart lines of text. `grep` is good for finding the lines you want.

More obscure (and less portable) are the [bash-specific regexp-like operators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), but they can be quick and fun to use.

```
$ MYDATE=`date`
$ echo $MYDATE
Mon Feb 8 16:28:04 EST 2010
$ echo ${MYDATE##* }
2010
```

Comment: I was just typing this exact same answer up when you posted it.  Only thing further I would add is to read the man pages for more formatting options.  In fact, I'd say nour now has a 'mandate' to read the man pages.

Comment: `$()` is easier to use and less error-prone than backticks (consider quotes and escaping).

Answer (score 1):

Grep is intended to print out an entire line that matches an RE. Getting it to print out only part of a line will be relatively difficult (at best).

With sed, you could use an RE that matched the rest of the line, and replace it with nothing, leaving the part you care about.

Comment: Well, getting GNU grep to print out only part of a line isn't difficult.  Try the -o (--only-matching) flag.

Comment: @Philip: Thanks -- I hadn't noticed that flag (though I've probably seen the help text for it a few hundred times...)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [Perl](http://www.perl.org/). It lifts heavily from `sed` and `awk` in terms of syntax, and is a complete programming language, with a *huge* library ([CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/)) to help you integrate with a variety of different systems.

I migrated to Perl when I found that my simple `awk`/`sed` solutions had to expand beyond the simplest cases.

Comment: And many other shell scripting languages (which simply means you can use a shebang line) work well for similar reasons.

Comment: That's very true. My preference is perl but I'm prepared to accept that's for historical reasons and today I may choose ruby/python etc.

Answer (score 1):

grep finds patterns in your files. It will not, however, modify your files.
sed finds patterns as well as do modification to your files. 
cut is a tool to "cut" columns in your files for display/(or to file). Use it if your task is very simple as just getting some columns. 
awk finds patterns in your file, and you can do modifications to it by creating another file. And awk does what sed, grep, cut does, so you can do almost anything with it with just 1 tool.

For Big sized files, use grep to find the pattern and pipe to awk/sed for manipulation of text.

for your example, if you want to get the YEAR of `date` command , use `date +%Y`.

various ways to get the YEAR of `date` command

```
$ date +%Y
2010

$ date | awk '{print $NF}'
2010

$ var=$(date)
$ set -- $var
$ eval echo \${${#}}
2010
```

Lastly, you can use regular expressions like some sed examples, but I find it easiest to just split the fields and get the last field. No complicated regex is needed.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep you can use -o (--only-matching) to show only the part of a matching line that matches a pattern.  Below the pattern is a Perl regular expression (-P, --perl-regexp) for four digits in a row:

```
$ date | grep -oP '\d{4}'
2010
```